# What does :force => true mean in the schema file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

If you look in db/schema.rb you will see something like:

```
create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
```

What does the `:force => true` mean?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

From the [Rails docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-create_table):

> **:force**
>
> Set to true to drop the table before creating it. Defaults to false.

Basically, this helps ensure database integrity. If you're manually tooling around with your migrations, it's helpful to ensure that you're creating new tables from a clean slate, rather than risking naming conflicts that stem from tables that have been created on a one-off basis.

Comment: excellent, i was just about to ask what that means.  i'll accept when i can! (allowed in 5 min)

Answer (score 3):

This simply drops the table before creation. Check the docs for more info here: [ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SchemaStatements](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-create_table)