# Can I change the ID to string when I work with Active Record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

It looks like the default :id is the integer, can I make it as a string?

Comment: do you have a specific reason for that?

Comment: Check this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200568/using-rails-how-can-i-set-my-primary-key-to-not-be-an-integer-typed-column

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can.

First run a migration:

```
create_table 'table' id: false, force: true do |t|
  t.string 'id', null: false
end
```

specifying the type `string` for the id.

Then in your model:

```
class Table < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = :id
end
```

Which will basically explicitly indicate that the string `id` is the primary key of the object instance.

Comment: what does force:true mean?

Comment: Here is a post that explains it perfectly :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18704290/what-does-force-true-mean-in-the-schema-file

Answer (score 1):

You should also consider looking up about `uuid`'s in Rails.

Despite it being mainly a `PostgreSQL` piece of functionality, we've found it works well with `MYSQL` too:

[image]

You can set it up like this:

```
#app/models/post.rb
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
   before_create :set_uuid

   private

   def set_uuid
      self.uuid = loop do
        random_token = SecureRandom.hex(5)
        break random_token unless self.class.exists? random_token
      end
   end
end
```

This can be accompanied - as pointed out by `Cyzanfar` - by replacing the `id` primary key with `uuid`. **Rails 4 automatically supports `uuid`**...

```
def change
   create_column :posts, :uuid, :string
   remove_column :posts, :id
   rename_column :posts, :uuid, :id
   execute "ALTER TABLE table ADD PRIMARY KEY (uuid);"
end
```

Some references:

- [Rails 4. Migrate table id to UUID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25681599/rails-4-migrate-table-id-to-uuid)
- http://www.lshift.net/blog/2013/09/30/changing-the-primary-key-type-in-ruby-on-rails-models/

--

Because Rails 4 supports `uuid` out of the box, this should work for you.

As mentioned, we use `uuid` for some of our models (it allows us to maintain functionality whilst keeping records unique)